# RichTextBox with source of rtf string displays incorrect

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, richtextbox, rtf

I have string with rft formatted text. I believe th string is correct, because when i enter in in notepad and save as rtf document, it is displayed correctly.
**The problem is that the highlight is not applied to the text when i try to pass it to RichTextBox.**

**Expected result is RichtextBox with grey bold text with highlighted word "PORTS", but i get only bold grey text**

**Rtf string that I pass to RichTextBox:**
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl;\red50\green146\blue255;\red235\green153\blue45;\red105\green105\blue105;}\viewkind0\uc1\pard\sa0\sl276\slmult1\cf0\f0\fs32\lang9\b\cf3\highlight2 PORTS\highlight0  documentation. \cf0\b0\par}"

**Rtf string that I save as rtf document:**
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl;\red50\green146\blue255;\red235\green153\blue45;\red105\green105\blue105;}\viewkind0\uc1\pard\sa0\sl276\slmult1\cf0\f0\fs32\lang9\b\cf3\highlight2 PORTS\highlight0  documentation. \cf0\b0\par}

**Example of rtf string that is displayed correctly(here text is not bald and not grey):**

"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\colortbl;\red50\green146\blue255;\red235\green153\blue45;\red105\green105\blue105;}\viewkind0\uc1\pard\sa0\sl276\slmult1\cf0\f0\fs30\lang9\highlight2 Port\highlight0  Serial \highlight2 port\highlight0  that uses COM \highlight2 port\highlight0 s\par}"

**Method that i use to set string to RithTextBox:**

```
private void UpdateRtf()
    {
      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(RtfString));
      TextRange range = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd);
      range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
```

Comment: Why not save the rtf to a file and use `RichTextBox1.LoadFile(rtfFIlePath);`

Comment: @preciousbetine I have lots of these RichTextBoxes and rtf strings. Don't think saving string to file every time is a good option